# Which other Stack Exchange sites have a userbase that would be interested in our site?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Now that we've reached Public Beta, part of our job is getting the word about Hardware Recommendations out. One way to do that is via [Community Ads](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/community-promotion-ads/). These ads are voted upon by the Stack Exchange community we want the ads to appear on, thus those sites should have relevance to Hardware Recommendations.

What graduated sites do you feel have users that would be interested in Hardware Recommendations?

Comment: I've seen some questions asking for open source hardware up at Open Source. If the volume gets higher, and we implement a custom reason, then you guys will surely get a mention there. :)

Comment: I think that Stack Overflow would have significant overlap, but if the idea is to connect with them via ads... :(

Comment: I agree @enderland, but [SO doesn't accept community promotion ads](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242163/186281), only Open Source project advertisements. :(

Answer (score 7):

In addition to the sites in [Adam's answer](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/216/102), the folks at **Graphic Design** may be interested. They even have a [hardware-recommendation](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hardware-recommendation) tag which mainly involves drawing tablets and printers

Comment: You'd have my support, [we get some that aren't a good fit for us anyway](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/61132/8708)

Comment: @JohnB, Link is down.....

Answer (score 6):

The obvious choices here (some of which will be way more relevant than others): **Super User**, **Software Recommendations**, **Server Fault**, and **Unix and Linux**.

There could be a few more such as Ask Different and Database Administrators that might find some use here. I see DBA as a strongly software-oriented site that won't need much from a hardware site.

Alternatively, we could aim at absolutely any site involving technology, whether it's hardware, software, programming, etc. There's bound to be people out there somewhere who will notice our ads and be interested because they just need a replacement laptop or something. The possibilities here are endless.

Comment: We can, of course, simply ask other communities if our ad would fit their site :)

Comment: @ArtOfCode That actually seems like a good option.

Comment: A few comments: Stack Overflow doesn't allow [community ads](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227265/why-no-community-promotion-ads-for-stack-overflow) and Raspberry Pi and Arduino are still beta so can't handle them yet.

Comment: @Andy Oh, right. Didn't even consider that.

Comment: @ArtOfCode, the "asking" part you mention is us posting to the suggested sites with our proposed ad. If it gets upvoted, they accept it. If it doesn't, they don't like it. As an example (and because Google returned Academia first), this is how such a page looks: http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1478/community-promotion-ads-2015 . If an add reaches a score of 6 it enters that site's rotation.

Comment: @Andy aye, but there's no harm in dropping into chat and seeking opinions

Answer (score 5):

**Ask Ubuntu** has a [hardware-recommendation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/hardware-recommendation) tag. There may be an audience on that site for us to promote to.

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking more on the direction of [Arduino](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/) , [Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) and similar.

These subject often require very specific hardware with specific non - common interfaces ( Rs323 , TTL , Rs485, serial etc ... ) for peripherals and accessories that are not always trivial to find ...

Comment: Both of these are beta sites. Unfortunately that means they don't have community ads yet. Good suggestions though.