# Community Promotion Ads - Let's advertise this site!

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, advertising

> There are ads that have already reached the 6-vote threshold and have been submitted to other sites. The following are the relevant ads that have been submitted:
>
> - [Arqade](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10168/community-promotion-ads-2015/10921#10921)
> - [Game Dev](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1849/community-promotion-ads-2015/2010#2010)
> - [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1340/community-promotion-ads-2015/2792#2792)
> - [Software Recs](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2299/community-promotion-ads-2015/2323#2323)
> - [Super User](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/9012/community-promotion-ads-2015/10790#10790)
>
> These posts will be displayed on those sites when they have reached the 6-vote threshold on that community.

---

We recently entered public beta, so we need to get word out to the rest of Stack Exchange about Hardware Recommendations Stack Exchange. One of the best ways of doing this is with Community Promotion Ads.

Here is part of the canonical spiel given on meta posts on graduated sites where we submit our ads for voting<sup>1</sup> (six upvotes and our ad is shown on the site), repurposed for a different use:

> #### What are Community Promotion Ads?
>
> Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will
> show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this
> question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are
> provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be
> shown.
>
> #### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?
>
> This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to
> visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following
> things:
>
> - the site's twitter account
> - useful tools or resources for physics research
> - interesting articles or findings for the curious
> - cool events or conferences
> - anything else your community would genuinely be interested in
>
> The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your
> community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote
> information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's
> interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to
> join.
>
> #### Why do we reset the ads every year?
>
> Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other
> things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads
> every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served
> their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This
> helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject
> matter of the community, but to the current status of the community.
> We reset the ads once a year, every December.
>
> The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an
> ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very
> valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good
> idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the
> process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale
> after a year of exposure.
>
> #### Image requirements
>
> - The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
> - Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
> - Must be GIF or PNG
> - No animated GIFs
> - Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

For more information, see [What's the best way to create a community ad for a beta site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247037/whats-the-best-way-to-create-a-community-ad-for-a-beta-site).

For ideas on what sites to advertise *to*, you may wish to see [Which other Stack Exchange sites have a userbase that would be interested in our site?](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215/which-other-stack-exchange-sites-have-a-userbase-that-would-be-interested-in-our)

I invite everyone to submit ideas for our ad as answers, following the above guidelines. Normally, these ads would link to the main site, but we could link to a specific tag or even individual questions. Let's use this question to collect ad designs that we can vote upon as a community and then submit to the relevant site(s). Please use one answer per design and indicate which site (or sites) you feel it'd fit best on, if is targeting a specific site.

Our suggested sites, so far, are:

- [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) - Has a [hardware-recommendation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hardware-recommendation) tag
- [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) - Has a [hardware-recommendation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/hardware-recommendation) tag
- [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) - Has a [hardware-recommendation](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hardware-recommendation) tag
- [Super User](https://superuser.com/) - Has a [hardware-rec](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hardware-rec) tag and a [hardware-selection](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hardware-selection) tag
- [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) - Does not have a specific tag
- [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) - Does not have a specific tag
- [Unix and Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) - Does not have a specific tag

---

<sup>1 Note: The sites on which the ad is posted *must* be related to our site's topic. Seasoned Advice would not be a good choice.</sup>

<sup>Note? Maybe not. Shameless copied from Open Source. Don't kill me, I think it's legal.</sup>

Comment: [Relevant.](http://meta.hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/215/which-other-stack-exchange-sites-have-a-userbase-that-would-be-interested-in-our)

Comment: @HDE226868 Thanks. Noted that in the post :)

Comment: Note: [you can also export your with dimensions 440 x 500 px](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/249739/216955) to make it look nicer on high density displays

Comment: Shouldn't this have [community-ads] tag?

Comment: @RubyJunk That tag is used to tell the site to actually display the ads located in these answers on *this* site. We obviously don't want that. This question carries the [advertising] tag, which carries discussion on the ads. [community-ads] are found on graduated sites - the ads located in those answers are displayed on that site once they attain a score of 6.

Answer (score 13):

[image]

(normal-size version [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c658W.png))

It's a start. All the little icons are public domain ([CC0](https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/)) from The Noun Project. Icons I either used or thought about using:

- https://thenounproject.com/term/electronic/4425/
- https://thenounproject.com/term/electronic/4427/
- https://thenounproject.com/term/electronic/17471/
- https://thenounproject.com/term/electronic/22242/
- https://thenounproject.com/term/electronic/22776/
- https://thenounproject.com/term/electronic/24988/
- https://thenounproject.com/term/electronic/25967/
- https://thenounproject.com/term/electronic/27579/
- https://thenounproject.com/term/electronic/28679/
- https://thenounproject.com/term/electronic/37791/
- https://thenounproject.com/term/electronic/37793/
- https://thenounproject.com/term/electronic/40597/

Comment: Oh my god. I've just fallen in love with an advertisement.

Comment: Will the small details be able to hold up when the image size is cut in half though?

Comment: @Adam I think so - [here's a normal-size render](http://i.stack.imgur.com/tP00k.png)

Comment: Oh nice. Looks awesome!

Comment: Posted on Software Recs! http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/2323/16399 and Super User! http://meta.superuser.com/a/10790/501116

Comment: Posted on [Software Recommendations](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/2552/133) and [SuperUser](http://meta.superuser.com/a/11580/269798) 2016 Edition

Answer (score 8):

[image: Man Your Battlestations - by Adam]

Comment: Ooh. Nice. I love this one as well :D

Comment: Hm, I could see this going really well on sites like Arqade and Game Dev.

Comment: @Zizouz212 Never thought about those. Arqade would be a great place for it.

Comment: **struggles to resist**. *Must. Post. With. Only. 5. Votes!!!*

Answer (score 6):

[image: Hardware Recommendations ad]

[Here's the Ai file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2239676/Stack%20Exchange/Hardware%20Recommendations/HardwareRecs-Ad.ai) if anyone would like to modify it

Comment: I know there are requirements for retina display ads. I don't see them in the OP though. Do you know what they are? (Asking only because this image so larger than the others so far, and I don't want it to be excluded if it still meets the retina display requirements)

Comment: This is the most official question I can find: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247063/do-the-double-size-retina-screen-community-ads-work-on-all-sites  There are [ads](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10168/community-promotion-ads-2015/10175#10175) that already do this. though

Comment: I like this one. It's generic (though has monitors in the picture), it doesn't specifically call out RAM, Monitors or Computer components in the text.

Comment: I've posted this on [Graphic Design](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/2792/8708) to get us started but anyone is welcome to post it on other relevant sites

Answer (score 5):

[image: Ad #2]

Comment: Still trying to iron out a good layout for this one. The text is tricky to work with. Any input is appreciated.

Comment: Not sponsored by http://downloadmoreram.com

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Comment: I love the color palette. I'm not sure "kit" is a great word to use though. Is it commonly used and I've just never heard it before?

Comment: @Adam Pretty sure it's common in British English.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Quit BIOS. Get a modern laptop.]

After a bit of back and forth in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/24493155#24493155), here's the final product. Special thanks to everyone, especially Art for really giving it the finishing touches.

Comment: This is something that could quite possibly go on to Programmers.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Answer (score -6):

This is a quick ad that I've made that is fairly simple, and can be used as an example. Of course, you peeps can use it as well :)

[image: Visit Hardware Recs SE!]